# Make @{<something>} have no effect on some specific row

Tags: tables

I have a table

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l @{: } l}
  nine   & 9 \\
  ten    & 10 \\
         & 0.\.9 \\
  eleven & 11
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the easist way to remove the colon in the third line?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the empty cell.

Comment: Thank you! `\multicolumn` is a nice solution.@daleif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\multocolumn{num}{spec}{contents}` to override the overall column specification. In this case it also hits the stuff you've added in between columns.

Here

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
```

Should be enough